# Destacar linha selecionada no RecyclerView

Tags: android-studio

Como destacar a linha selecionada(clicada) no recyclerview? O listview era automático. 
Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá!

Vou presumir que você está falando sobre o efeito `rippe`, que é o efeito da imagem abaixo:

[image: Imagem com efeito rippe]

Basta colocar os atributos abaixo no layout pai inflato pelo seu adapter.

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Exemplo:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground">
```